# exe made by pyinstaller crashes at calling matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, pyinstaller

I am trying to use matplotlib with Tkinter to create a stand-alone executable by pyinstall (command: `pyinstaller --onefile main.py`).
The program works at the stations where the python installed. However, at the computers without any installed python the program crashes at the line, which calls pyplot (`fig = plt.Figure()`). The crash occurs without any error.

I've tried upgrading/downgrading matplotlib or pyinstaller, changed Figure() to figure(), re-installed numpy, nothing helped, and I do not know what to do else. I ran it from command prompt and I haven't seen any messages.

UPD: I've tried `--debug-imports` flag, and found the only line that differs between working and not working station is "exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)" that exists only in the debug-log of the working program. The line occurs after deprecation warning "D:\Prog_files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py:493: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The MATPLOTLIBDATA environment variable was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3."

Do you have any ideas on how I can fix it?

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

def setplot(x, y):
       
    fig = plt.Figure()
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    (l, ) = ax1.plot(x, y)

def Quit():
    global root
    root.destroy()
    
def LoadFile(): 
    xx = list(range(0,100))
    yy = [i*i for i in xx]
    setplot(xx, yy)
   
root = Tk()
root.geometry('700x500')

panelFrame = Frame(root, height = 60, bg = 'gray')
panelFrame.pack(side = 'top', fill = 'x')

loadBtn = Button(panelFrame, text = 'Plot', command =  LoadFile)
quitBtn = Button(panelFrame, text = 'Exit', command = Quit)
loadBtn.pack()

loadBtn.place(x = 10, y = 10, width = 70, height = 40)
quitBtn.place(x = 100, y = 10, width = 70, height = 40)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you try the various things described to help find out what happens when your app doesn’t start https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#finding-out-what-went-wrong

Comment: In particular, start your exe from a command prompt and edit the full error message you get into your question.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the program crashes silently, i.e. without writing anything to the console window, or without showing a messagebox containing an error message?

Comment: Ive usually seen `matplotlib` producing tons of errors with `tkinter` when compiled with `pyinstaller`

Comment: @barny, I run it from the command prompt and do not see any error.

Comment: @pts, the only message in the debug-all regime is "LOADER: Back to parent (RC = -1066598274)" after calling matplotlib. Without debug-all command prompt silently ends the program :(.

Comment: did somebody find a solution for this? 3 months after, still no solution, but the error persists.

Comment: @giosans, unfortunately not. Eventually, I used Tkinter canvas tools for drawing plots and that worked well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem and after several searches I found a recipe that works. These are my configurations with Anaconda:

- python version 3.6
- pyinstaller version 3.6
- matplotlib version 3.0.3

Do not use pyinstaller with "--onefile" option so in the folder "dist" there will be various ".dll" files. And here is the problem, the file "libiomp5md.dll" is missing!

Then just copy to the folder "dist" the file "libiomp5md.dll" which is located in the Anaconda installation folder ...\Anaconda3\Library\bin

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exact issue in a project that used

- matplotlib
- pandas
- pillow
- pyinstaller
- pysimplegui

After endless hours trying a million different solutions (DLLs, cmd line parameters, --paths="", hooks, reading the docs, trying cx freeze and py2exe instead etc.) i fixed it randomly by simply using a specific combination of package versions... **so frustrating...**

- python 3.7.10
- matplotlib 3.4.1
- pyinstaller 4.3
- pysimplegui 4.38

The rest of the packages that I mentioned don't seem to have made a difference. I really hope it helps, i know how painful it is. I suggest creating a new anaconda environment from scratch and installing the specific versions with `conda install -c conda-forge -n {envNameYouWant} pyinstaller=4.3`